# c language sort by value in structure

Tags: c

I can't understand what wrong here.
I run debug and can't find the problem it's supposed to work.
the problem is that if I insert few students and then chose (3 option) to sort it by nakaz, it prints 0 instead of the actual value number.
but I can see that it all good in the F7
thank you very much
in c language

[ilustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfXNX.jpg)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h>


    typedef struct student* ps; //struct student pointer
    typedef struct student student;
```

Comment: Punctuation, please.

Comment: I have posted my suspected answer below but please make a much stronger effort to clean up the code and your grammar when making posts.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the latest code. You need to give your `typedef struct student` a name, and it looks like the `main()` isn't properly terminated.  The answer below from @Player1st looks like a correct one to me.

Comment: It appears you are using a C++ compiler for C code.  For best C results, use a C compiler.  Review `typedef struct student {...}` usage.

Comment: @nim There is a "secret" way to reduce coding errors not well given to beginners.  Enable all compiler warnings.  `printf("The student %s points is %lf \n", head->name, head->nakaz);` should have warned something like "warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'int'".  This is faster feedback than posting on SO.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the wrong output type on the points printf.  You have it set to `"%lf"` when it should be `"%d"` based on the expected integer type of the variable:

```
void printAllStudents(ps head){
    while (head != NULL){
        printf("The student %s points is %d \n", head->name, head->nakaz);
        head = head->next;//printing all dogs
}
```